# Select a single id out of a loop

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I have an array that is being looped through to get all of the id's. The id's are coming from an aura:iteration. I need to index the loop so I can pull the correct Id out when a user clicks on a specific li item.

Component:

```
<ul>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact" indexVar="studentNo">
    <li class="minli">
        <div class="studentPhotoDiv"><ui:outputRichText value="{!contact.Photo__c}" class="studentPhoto"/></div>
        <div class="studentNameDiv"><ui:outputText value="{!contact.Name}" class="studentName" aura:id="studentName"></ui:outputText></div>
        <a class="studentElement" data-index="{!studentNo}" data-id="{!contact.Id}" id="studentIdElement"/>
        <div class="studentSelectDiv"><ui:button label="Check-in" class="studentSelect" press="{!c.studentSelect}"></ui:button></div>
        <br style="clear: both;" />
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

Client-Side Controller:

```
studentSelect : function(component,event,helper) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('studentElement');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(studentElement) {
    var elementsLength = elements.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < elementsLength; i++) {
        var studentId = studentElement.dataset.id;
        console.log("Student ID: "+studentId[i]);
    }
});
```

I have tried to use a for loop to iterate through them but it just breaks it. I have also looked into Array.prototype.some and Array.prototype.every but neither of those seemed to help me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open for a little change, remove the  class/ divs/ids etc.. that has been used all over. I am assuming you want to call the studentSelect function on button click , You can do this simply using basic button code

I have used basic HTML button, as far as I know you cannot assign a variable value to aura:id hence took this route instead of ui:button/lightning:button

Change the ui:button to :

```
<button id="{!contact.Id}" onclick="{!c.studentSelect}">Check-In </button>
```

In your controller you can do

```
studentSelect : function(component,event,helper) {
        var elm = event.target.id;
        //This should give you the contact Id associated to the button that you clicked in iteration list. 
        //You can alter the value to pass contact name by passing name to id eg: id="{!contact.name}" in your component.
        console.log(elm);
    }
```

This should give you the contact Id of the li corresponding to the button click.

Comment: Happy I was able to help :)